# Javascript datepicker exclude weekends, an array of dates & a specific day each week

Tags: javascript, jquery, date, datepicker

I'm trying to exclude weekends, an array of dates and monday of every week from my datepicker. This is what I have so far:

```
var disableddates = ["12-21-2015", "12-24-2015", "1-4-2016", "1-5-2016"];
function DisableSpecificDates(date) {

  var m = date.getMonth();
  var d = date.getDate();
  var y = date.getFullYear();

  var currentdate = (m + 1) + '-' + d + '-' + y ;

  for (var i = 0; i < disableddates.length; i++) {

  if ($.inArray(currentdate, disableddates) != -1 ) {
      return [false];
    }
  }

  var weekend = $.datepicker.noWeekends(date);
  return [(weekend[0] || date.getDay() == 1)]; // I'm trying to disable Monday here

}

$(function() {
  $("#date").datepicker( {
    minDate: setMinDate,
    maxDate: "+2M",
    beforeShowDay: DisableSpecificDates
  });
});
```

The specific dates (stored in the `disableddates` array) are excluded, as are the weekends, but Monday is still selectable - does any one know where i'm going wrong, or an alternative solution to this?

Comment: not sure what $.datepicker.noWeekends(date); does, but why don´t you try inverting the order? `return [(date.getDay() == 1 || weekend[0]  )];`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So if I understood right you want just tuesday-friday dates. Checked what `$.datepicker.noWeekends(date);` does and it will return a 1 if it´s a weekday and 0 if it´s a weekend date. So let's check your code:

`weekend[0] || date.getDay() == 1`

If `weekend[0]` is false, that means that `date.getDay() == 0` or `== 6` (sunday or saturday). But `weekend[0]` will always be true for `date.getDay() == 1` . So you are always allowing monday, as `true || true == true`

What you want is:

```
return [(weekend[0] && date.getDay() != 1)];
```

Which means allow it if it´s a week day different than monday

Comment: Ah of corse! thank you for the breakdown, I understand my error now.

Comment: No problem! Was an easy fix but more useful to know why it happend :)

Answer (score 1):

I found:

```
0: Sunday
1: Monday 
2: Tuesday 
3: Wednesday
4: Thursday
5: Friday 
6: Saturday
```

So that part is right. I also see you don't pass `date` inside `DisableSpecificDates`

I'd try (simplified):

```js
$("#datepicker").datepicker({
  beforeShowDay: function(date) {
    var day = date.getDay();
    return [(day != 1 && day != 0 && day != 6)];
  }
});
```

```html
<link href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.3/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<p>Date:
  <input type="text" id="datepicker">
</p>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/hLa2uuov/2/

Comment: If I `return [day != 1];` instead of `return [(weekend[0]];` I just get the datepicker excluding every monday and my array of dates, If I `return [(weekend[0]];` instead of `return [day != 1];` I get all the weekends excluded and my array of dates... I basically need to combine both of these (so I get no monday AND no weekends) - any ideas?

Comment: @JonKyte Fiddle does exactly what you want

Comment: The 12/24/15 and 1/5/15 are still selectable when the OP asked for it to be disabled. Though the rest of your answer seems correct.

Comment: @Scanner OP get his question answered, not totally prechewed code (although it already looks like baby food). He obviously know what to do from here.