# Disable date in jquery datepicker

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I have an ASP textbox with datepicker and datepicker is named as input-datepicker and its comes when focus is on textbox so am not able to execute this code :-

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-md-3 control-label" for="state-normal">
        Check-In Date
    </label>
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <asp:TextBox ID="txtcheckindate" runat="server" CssClass="form-control input-datepicker" data-date-format="yyyy-mm-dd" placeholder="yyyy-mm-dd"></asp:TextBox>
        <span class="help-block">
            <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="rfvcheckindate" runat="server" ForeColor="#E7935C" SetFocusOnError="true" ControlToValidate="txtcheckindate" ValidationGroup="val1" Display="Dynamic" ErrorMessage="Enter Check In date"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
        </span>
    </div>
</div>
```

I want to disable dates from now to 48hrs ahead. I have tried this code but it is not working at all, and not even giving any errors in the developer console.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#txtcheckindate").datepicker().datepicker("setDate", new Date());
    $("#txtcheckindate").datepicker({
        dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',
        beforeShowDay: noWeekendsOrHolidays
    });

    function noWeekendsOrHolidays(selDate) {
        var noNext2Days = chkNext2Days(selDate);
        return noNext2Days;
    };

    function chkNext2Days(selectedDate) {
        var today = new Date();
        if (isEqual(selectedDate, today)) 
            return [false, '', ''];

        today.setDate(today.getDate() + 1);
        if (isEqual(selectedDate, today)) 
           return [false, '', ''];

        today.setDate(today.getDate() + 1);
        if (isEqual(selectedDate, today)) 
            return [false, '', ''];

        return [true, '', ''];
    }

    function isEqual(srcDate, tarDate) {
        if ((srcDate.getDate() == tarDate.getDate()) && (srcDate.getMonth() == tarDate.getMonth()) && (srcDate.getFullYear() == tarDate.getFullYear())) {
            return true;
        } else { 
            return false; }
        }
    });
```

Can anyone show me where the mistake is?

Comment: may be this can help you http://www.spiceforms.com/blog/how-to-disable-dates-in-jquery-datepicker-a-short-guide/

Comment: I have googled the same thing and have tried this but not working. please check my current code and guide, because it is not working and not even giving any error

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Javascript datepicker exclude weekends, an array of dates & a specific day each week](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34314242/javascript-datepicker-exclude-weekends-an-array-of-dates-a-specific-day-each)

Comment: @Thomas  actually what  happening is...

It is not executing any condition and returns with no error

Answer (score 0):

Try to change this

```
$("#txtcheckindate").datepicker().datepicker("setDate", new Date());
    $("#txtcheckindate").datepicker({
        dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',
        beforeShowDay: noWeekendsOrHolidays
    });
```

for this

```
$("#txtcheckindate").datepicker({
    setDate: new Date(),
    dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',
    beforeShowDay: noWeekendsOrHolidays
});
```